# Expand dates in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have a problem, where I have a data table with start and end date together with an ID. A new table should have the same ID with one column date, containing a sequence of days between first and last day, one day for each row, i.e.

```
old.table
ID          first.date               last.date
1           2001-01-01               2001-01-03
2           2002-02-01               2002-02-04

new table
ID          date
1           2001-01-01
1           2001-01-02
1           2001-01-03
2           2002-02-01
2           2002-02-02
2           2002-02-03
2           2002-02-04
```

I know, that calling

```
seq(first.date,last.date,"day")
```

creates such a sequence. However, calling

```
old.table[,date := seq(first.date,last.date,"day")])
```

throws the exception

```
 Error in seq.Date(first.date, last.date, "day") : 
'from' must be of length 1
```

meaning, that vectorizing the input is not possible (at least not like this).

Is there a way, to get the desired solution?

Answer (score 6):

As `seq` takes only a single element in `from` and `to`, we can group by 'id' (if there are no duplicates) and then do the `seq`

```
setDT(old.table)[, .(date = seq(first.date, last.date, by = '1 day')), by = ID]  
#   ID       date
#1:  1 2001-01-01
#2:  1 2001-01-02
#3:  1 2001-01-03
#4:  2 2002-02-01
#5:  2 2002-02-02
#6:  2 2002-02-03
#7:  2 2002-02-04
```

If the 'ID' is also duplicated, then group by the sequence of rows instead

```
setDT(old.table)[, .(date = seq(first.date, last.date, by = '1 day')), 
                        by = .(ID, ID2 = seq_len(nrow(old.table)))]
```